# Remove element of internal field array MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following situation:

```
{ code: 0, array:[{ _id: 1, ....}, { _id: 2, ....}, { _id: 18, ....}]}
```

I need to remove the element inside 'array' field matching the '_id' field.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html) & [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/):

```
db.yourCollection.update(
    { },  // <-- your selection criteria
    { $pull: { array: { _id: 2 } }  // <-- what you want to remove from which field
)
```